# MySQL Workbench Migration Fails libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

OK, i am trying to run the migration wizard in MySQL Workbench.
All goes ok until it comes to the "Bulk Data Transfer".

It then fails with the following error

```
 relocation error: /usr/bin/wbcopytables: symbol mysql_options4, version libmysqlclient_18  
not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference

ERROR: Copy helper exited with an error: Worker exited with status 127
```

I have libmysqlclient18 installed and i have Workbench version 6.1.7.

When i try and get the latest version from their website and install to 6.2.4 i then get a dependancy issue with libnetcdf6.

Any ideas?

Update: sorry forgot OS details

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

Regards
Liam

Comment: Exactly what Operation System (and OS version)?

Comment: A dependency problem? On Windows? On libnetcdf6? That sounds weird. WB might indirectly use such a lib (though I never heard of that, is it really a system lib?) but it's not an inherent problem of MySQL Workbench, but rather a system issue, I'd say.